# Cross product of 2 2D vectors

Tags: c, math, vector, 2d

Can anyone provide an example of a function that returns the cross product of **TWO** 2d vectors? I am trying to implement [this algorithm](http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html).

C code would be great. Thanks.

---

**EDIT:** found another way todo it that works for 2D and is dead easy.

```
bool tri2d::inTriangle(vec2d pt) {
    float AB = (pt.y-p1.y)*(p2.x-p1.x) - (pt.x-p1.x)*(p2.y-p1.y);
    float CA = (pt.y-p3.y)*(p1.x-p3.x) - (pt.x-p3.x)*(p1.y-p3.y);
    float BC = (pt.y-p2.y)*(p3.x-p2.x) - (pt.x-p2.x)*(p3.y-p2.y);

    if (AB*BC>0.f && BC*CA>0.f)
        return true;
    return false;    
}
```

Comment: Is this for work or home work?

Comment: This is for personal enjoyment. Why?

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243945/calculating-a-2d-vectors-cross-product

Comment: @tm1rbt -- Because SOers like to know when we are doing or helping with homework so that we can claim the credit transfers to our own academic transcripts.

Comment: don't be so rude and try reading it again "Given that the definition requires at least three dimensions, how does one calculate the cross product of two 2d vectors?"

Comment: @tm1rbrt: Just to know; because I know people who don't do either, elude their work and get it done thru' SO. Usually SO is for asking doubts; helping is something, but doing someone else's work is totally something else. Btw, don't use strong words like _moron_.

Comment: How on earth can you ask for a function to calculate a cross-product, accept an answer that's incorrect, and then post a function that returns a boolean?  I'm voting this down and voting to close.

Comment: Agree with @duffymo. I think the topic creator wanted to calculate a cross product for his algorithm, but ended up using a different method that doesn't need vector algebra at all.
But I'm not voting this question down.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

(Note: *The* cross-product of 2 vectors is only defined in 3D and [7D spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product).)

The code computes the *z*-component of 2 vectors lying on the *xy*-plane:

```
vec2D a, b;
...
double z = a.x * b.y - b.x * a.y;
return z;
```

Comment: Wow. Would like to give you an extra +1 for that link!

Comment: @tm1rbrt: That `CrossProduct` should be a full 3D cross-product. You can always add back the two 0 components.

Comment: The cross product of two vectors in 3D space is a 3D vector, yet your code only returns a double.  What good is one component?

Comment: The 3-D cross product of two vectors in the x/y plane is always along the z axis, so there's no point in providing two additional numbers known to be zero.  Another way to look at it: the closest 2-D equivalent to a 3-D cross product is an operation (the one above) that returns a scalar.

Comment: Also, I want to assure you that the above operation will in fact work correctly with the algorithm you link to.  If you work it out, the dot product of the resulting cross product vectors simplifies to a simple product of the resulting scalars.  Your updated version above could be considered a simplified (and nicely symmetric!) version of this:  by reducing the problem to comparing the signs of the resulting scalars, you can determine that the orientation of the original triangle is redundant.

Comment: @comingstorm - 2D doesn't necessarily mean in the xy-plane.  I understand vectors well enough to know what special case you're talking about, but there's nothing in the original question that spells out that restriction.  The updated answer that's provided is the correct, general answer.  In spite of the fact that your answer was accepted it's not correct for the general case.

Comment: Hey, first off, that's not *my* answer;  second, it is, in fact, correct.  The OQ was specifically about 2D vectors:  an answer phrased in terms of 3D vectors would be missing the point, and therefore incorrect.  Also, if you take a look at the link in the OQ, you will notice that his update, which you slagged for returning a boolean, is a (correct) implementation of his declared objective -- a point-in-triangle algorithm implemented for 2D vectors.

Answer (score 0):

[Mathworld Cross Product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html)