# How to calculate the GPS Coordinates 5m Left and Right from you Position?

Tags: gps, coordinates

maybe some of you know that there are GPS tools out there that are used in Motorsports. A lot of them deliver the following function: If you drive with your car and you press a button at a certain point this GPS Coordinate will be stored and every time you drive over this coordinate a LapTime will be stored. For a small application a need a similar function. But here is my problem: Since you will never hit the exact Coordinate twice these tools store the coordinates of a Line and if you hit one of the coordinates of this line the Lap is finished. How do I calculate such a line? If you look at my Picture, the red dot is the coordinate where the user hits the button to start a lap and the green Line is what the device stores and uses as a virtual finish line and not only the Coordinate where the red dot is. Any Idea how I can calculate such a line? I really don't get it since the line is never ideal directed to north or south.
[image]

Thank you very much

twickl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "see" on which side of the line the car is.

You can take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3838319/how-can-i-check-if-a-point-is-below-a-line-or-not) previous stackoverflow question. However, you should keep in mind that GPS accuracy varies by 5-50 metres, and also the speed at which the car is moving might introduce further error to such model.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to take at least the previous GPS co-ordinate to be able to work out the direction the car was moving when the button was hit, and from that you can get the left and right.

I can see it being problematic though. As you probably know, GPS is only accurate to a distance of 5 metres (at best). And depending on how often you're polling for a GPS co-ordinate, you could be a few metres out again (given that the car is presumably moving at a fair speed!). You also have issues if the finish line is on or close to a corner, as you would likely not be calculating the direction of the car correctly.

Interesting app though!