# cross product in TinyOs?

Tags: vector, tinyos, nesc, cross-product

how can i make [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) between two vector in [Tinyos](http://www.tinyos.net/) (nesC)?

if i have `position=p1+x*ex+y*ey;`; where ex,ey: are vector.

i am searching for that but couldn't find any thing helped !!!

so is there any helpful way to do this ? if i go to the definition of cross product there is angle which i don't now how to get it from the two vector ?

Answer (score 0):

if you have two vectors a and b (a = (a1, a2, a3) and b = (b1, b2, b3)) then cross product can be computed using following formula:

a x b = (a2*b3 - a3*b2, a3*b1 - a1*b3, a1*b2 - a2*b1)

Comment: if the two vector from two components? (a1,a2) ?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/243945/calculating-a-2d-vectors-cross-product) is another question that has a good explanation  regarding 2d case.