# Relative position of a point within a quadrilateral

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry

I am trying to find the easiest way to determine a relative position of a point within a quadrilateral. The known are (see figure) the positions of points 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 in the xy-coordinate system: x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5.

[image]

Also known are the positions of points 1, 2, 3, and 4 in the ξ-η coordinate systems (see figure).

From this data, I want to determine what are the ξ and η for point 5.

**Results**

Thank you to all who anwsered! I find the solution by @dbc and @agentp similar. Also I find this solution better than the perspective transformation solution by @MBo, since I do not have to compute the inverse of a matrix (Ax=B --> x=inv(A)*B).

I get the following result for:

```
u = 0.5 * (ξ + 1)
v = 0.5 * (η + 1)
```

In my case all points are within the rectangle, therefore u>0 and v>0.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have here is a [2d bilinear blended surface](http://designer.mech.yzu.edu.tw/article/articles/course/%282000-10-26%29%20Geometric%20properties%20of%20surfaces2.htm).  For simplicity, let's change its coordinates to range from zero to one:

```
u = 0.5 * (ξ + 1)
v = 0.5 * (η + 1)
```

In that case, the surface evaluator can be expressed as

```
F(u, v) = P1 + u * (P2 - P1) + v * ((P4 + u * (P3 - P4)) - (P1 + u * (P2 - P1)))
```

I.e., for a given `u`, construct a line passing through the following two points:

```
Pv0 = P1 + u * (P2 - P1);
Pv1 = P4 + u * (P3 - P4);
```

then interpolate between then for given `v`

```
F(u, v) = Pv0 + v * (Pv1 - Pv0)
```

What you seek are values `(u,v)` such that `F(u, v) = P5`.  This will occur for given `u` when the line from `Pv0` to `Pv1` passes through `P5`, which will occur when `P5 - Pv0` is parallel to `Pv1 - Pv0` -- i.e. when their [2d cross](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CrossProduct.html) is zero:

```
cross2d(P5 - Pv0, Pv1 - Pv0) = 0
```

⇒

```
cross2d(P5                 - (P1 + u * (P2 - P1)),  
        P4 + u * (P3 - P4) - (P1 + u * (P2 - P1))) = 0
```

Now, the [2d cross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/243945/calculating-a-2d-vectors-cross-product) of two 2d vectors `A ⨯ B` is given by `Ax*By - Ay*Bx`, so that equation becomes

```
(x5 - (x1 + u * (x2 - x1))) * (y4 + u * (y3 - y4) - (y1 + u * (y2 - y1))) - (y5 - (y1 + u * (y2 - y1))) * (x4 + u * (x3 - x4) - (x1 + u * (x2 - x1))) = 0
```

[Expanding this expression out and collecting collecting together terms in `u`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x5+-+%28x1+%2B+u+*+%28x2+-+x1%29%29%29+*+%28y4+%2B+u+*+%28y3+-+y4%29+-+%28y1+%2B+u+*+%28y2+-+y1%29%29%29+-+%28y5+-+%28y1+%2B+u+*+%28y2+-+y1%29%29%29+*+%28x4+%2B+u+*+%28x3+-+x4%29+-+%28x1+%2B+u+*+%28x2+-+x1%29%29%29), we get

```
    u^2 * (x1*y3 - x1*y4 - x2*y3 + x2*y4 + (-x3)*y1 + x3*y2 + x4*y1 - x4*y2)
  + u *   (-x1*y3 + 2*x1*y4 - x1*y5 - x2*y4 + x2*y5 + x3*y1 - x3*y5 - 2*x4*y1 + x4*y2 + x4*y5 + x5*y1 - x5*y2 + x5*y3 - x5*y4)
  +       (-x1*y4 + x1*y5 + x4*y1 - x4*y5 - x5*y1 + x5*y4)
= 0
```

This is now a quadratic equation over `u`, and can be [solved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance#A_better_algorithm) as such.  Note that in cases where the top and bottom edges of your quadrilateral are parallel then the quadratic devolves into a linear equation; your quadratic equation solver must needs handle this.

```
        double a = (x1 * y3 - x1 * y4 - x2 * y3 + x2 * y4 + (-x3) * y1 + x3 * y2 + x4 * y1 - x4 * y2);
        double b = (-x1 * y3 + 2 * x1 * y4 - x1 * y5 - x2 * y4 + x2 * y5 + x3 * y1 - x3 * y5 - 2 * x4 * y1 + x4 * y2 + x4 * y5 + x5 * y1 - x5 * y2 + x5 * y3 - x5 * y4);
        double c = (-x1 * y4 + x1 * y5 + x4 * y1 - x4 * y5 - x5 * y1 + x5 * y4);

        double[] solutions = Quadratic.Solve(a, b, c);
```

There may be more than one solution.  There might also be no solutions for a degenerate quadrilateral.

Having solved for value(s) of `u`, finding the equivalent `v` is straightforward.  Given points

```
Pv0 = P1 + u * (P2 - P1);
Pv1 = P4 + u * (P3 - P4);
```

you seek `v` such that

```
v * (Pv1 - Pv0) = P5 - Pv0;
```

Pick the coordinate index 0 or 1 such that `|(Pv1 - Pv0)[index]|` is *maximized*.  (If both coordinates are almost zero, then give up -- there's no solution for this specific `u`.  Then set

```
v = (P5 - Pv0)[index] / (Pv1 - Pv0)[index];
```

Finally, if you have more that one solution, prefer a solution inside the `[u, v]` boundaries of the blend.  Then finally set

```
ξ = 2 * u - 1;
η = 2 * v - 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a standard finite element parameterization
(The question doesn't specify a particular mapping, but I imagine someone might be interested in this specific case)

```
 {x, y}  == (
             (1 - eta) (1 - ci) {p1x, p1y}  +
             (1 - eta) (1 + ci) {p2x, p2y}   + 
             (1 + eta) (1 + ci) {p3x, p3y} +
             (1 + eta) (1 - ci) {p4x, p4y} )/4
```

This can be solved in closed form for {eta,ci}, but the expression is pretty unwieldy to post.

In practice, compute these constants:

```
 ax = p1x + p2x + p3x + p4x
 bx = p1x - p2x - p3x + p4x
 cx = p1x + p2x - p3x - p4x
 dx = p1x - p2x + p3x - p4x
 ay = p1y + p2y + p3y + p4y
 by = p1y - p2y - p3y + p4y
 cy = p1y + p2y - p3y - p4y;
 dy = p1y - p2y + p3y - p4y;
```

Solve this quadratic for `eta` :

```
 (ax by - bx ay) - 4 (by  x - bx y) +
  eta (dx ay - cx by + bx  cy - ax dy + 4 (x dy - dx y)) +
  eta^2 (cx dy - dx cy) == 0
```

then get `ci` as:

```
 ci = ((-ax + eta cx + 4 x)/(-bx + eta dx))
```

If the polygon is not too distorted just one of the solutions will satisfy `-1<eta<1` and  `-1<ci<1`

Comment: Unfortunately this formulation is quadratic in the unknowns and the solution is not unique. The perspective approach is better in this respect.

Comment: Right -- however If the actual problem is a finite element formulation then you need to use this.

Answer (score 2):

*Referring to the self-answer of @blaz (please vote up the answers of @blaze, @dbc and @agentp)*

For everybody who is not willing to copy the formulas by hand, here is the formula as C# code:

```cs
    double v_sqrt = Math.Sqrt(
        4 * (
        (x3 - x4) * (y1 - y2) - (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4)) * (x4 * (-1 * y + y1) + x1 * (y - y4) + x * (-1 * y1 + y4)) +
        Math.Pow(
        (x3 * y - x4 * y - x3 * y1 + 2 * x4 * y1 - x4 * y2 + x1 * (y + y3 - 2 * y4) + x2 * (-1 * y + y4) + x * (-1 * y1 + y2 - y3 + y4))
        , 2)
        );

    double u_sqrt = Math.Sqrt(
            4 * ((x3 - x4) * (y1 - y2) - (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4))
            * (
                x4 * (-1 * y + y1) + x1 * (y - y4) + x * (-1 * y1 + y4)
            ) +
            Math.Pow(
            (x3 * y - x4 * y - x3 * y1 + 2 * x4 * y1 - x4 * y2 + x1 * (y + y3 - 2 * y4) + x2 * (-1 * y + y4) + x * (-1 * y1 + y2 - y3 + y4))
            , 2)
        );

    double k = 1 / (2 * ((x3 - x4) * (y1 - y2) - (x1 - x2) * (y3 - y4)));
    double l = 1 / (2 * ((x1 - x4) * (y2 - y3) - (x2 - x3) * (y1 - y4)));

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    double v1 = l *
        (x2 * y - x3 * y + x4 * y + x * y1 - 2 * x2 * y1 + x3 * y1 - x * y2 - x4 * y2 + x * y3 - x1 * (y - 2 * y2 + y3) - x * y4 + x2 * y4 +
        v_sqrt);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    double u1 = -1 * k *
        (-x2 * y + x3 * y - x * y1 - x3 * y1 + 2 * x4 * y1 + x * y2 - x4 * y2 - x * y3 + x1 * (y + y3 - 2 * y4) + x * y4 + x2 * y4 +
        u_sqrt);

    double v2 = -1 * l *
        (x1 * y + x3 * y - x4 * y - x * y1 - 2 * x3 * y1 + x * y2 - -2 * x1 * y2 + x4 * y2 - x * y3 + x1 * y3 + x * y4 - x2 * (y - 2 * y1 + y4) +
        v_sqrt);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    double u2 = k *
        (x2 * y - x3 * y + x4 * y + x * y1 + x3 * y1 - 2 * x4 * y1 - x * y2 + x4 * y2 + x * y3 - x1 * (y + y3 - 2 * y4) - x * y4 - x2 * y4 +
        u_sqrt);
```

In most cases it is u1 and v1 so there should not be the need for computing the other ones.

I used it to calibrate the coordinates of a Pegasus Air-Pen device (ultrasonic stylus) on a sheet of paper. It does work best if your coordinates for point 1 to 5 are also >= 0.

*Sry for posting this as an answer but it is too long for a comment and I think it is a valuable help for this post as it would be for me.*

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate a matrix of perspective transformation, that maps 4 points of source quadrilateral to 4 points of destination quadrilateral [(example)](http://xenia.media.mit.edu/~cwren/interpolator/) ([more mathemathics](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ph/texfund/texfund.pdf)), then apply this transformation  to coordinates of 5th point (multiply matrix by coordinate vector)